# Included file is shown outside of template

Tags: drupal, include

I'm trying to develop a module for Drupal, I'm quite new.

The following piece of code is working well, except for the included file. The contents of the included file are being show outside of the template, while the rest is correctly shown inside the template. Why does this happen and how to solve this?

```
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'helloworld') . '/helloworld.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));

function helloworld_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['helloworld'] = array(
    'title'            => t('Hello world'),
    'page callback'    => 'helloworld_output',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function helloworld_display(){

    include_once ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/helloworld.display.php');
}
/*
* Display output
*/
function helloworld_output() {
  header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline');
  $output = "<div id='hw_wrapper'>";
  $output .= helloworld_display();
  $output .= 'hej';
  $output .= "</div>";
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the helloworld.display.php file?

Comment: just <?php

 echo "Another hello world"; so this shouldn't cause this I reckon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use the following code.

```
function helloworld_init() {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'helloworld') . '/helloworld.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));
}

function helloworld_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['helloworld'] = array(
    'title' => t('Hello world'),
    'page callback' => 'helloworld_output',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/*
* Display output
*/
function helloworld_output() {
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline');

  return array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="hw_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#theme' => 'helloworld_mypage',
  );
}

function helloworld_theme() {
  return array(
    'helloworld_mypage' => array(
      'variables' => array(),
      'template' => 'helloworld-mypage',
    ),
  );
}
```

Rename the helloworld.display.php file as helloworld-mypage.tpl.php, and put it in the directory containing the helloworld.module file.

I will add some notes:

- [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is used when the CSS file needs to be included in any page. If you need to use it just in your page, you could use the following code. (Replace `helloworld_output()` I shown before with the following code; the rest is the same as before.)

  ```
  function helloworld_output() {
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline');

    return array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="hw_wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#theme' => 'helloworld_mypage',
      '#attached' => array(
        'css' => drupal_get_path('module', 'helloworld') . '/helloworld.css',
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- If you had a single call to `drupal_add_http_header()`, you could replace it with an item in the #attached array, as in the following code.

  ```
  function helloworld_output() {
    return array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="hw_wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#theme' => 'helloworld_mypage',
      '#attached' => array(
        'css' => drupal_get_path('module', 'helloworld') . '/helloworld.css',
        'drupal_add_http_header' => array('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

  See [drupal_process_attached()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_attached/7) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

***MYMODULE.module***

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 *
 * @return An array of menu items.
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['test'] = array(
      'title' => 'Test',
      'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_test_page',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback
 */
function MYMODULE_test_page(){
  // Drupal 7 way to get path of files directory
  $path = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');
  // Uncomment for Drupal 6
  // $path = file_directory_path() .'/files'; 
  $variables['content'] = htmlentities(@file_get_contents($path .'/test.php'));
  return theme('test_page', $variables);
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 *
 * @return Array of defined theme functions
 * 
 */
function MYMODULE_theme() {

  $themes = array(
      'test_page' => array(
          'variables' => array('variables' => array()),
          'template' => 'test-page',
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/theme'
      )
  );

  return $themes;
}
```

***theme/test-page.tpl.php***

```
<div class="myclass">
  <pre>
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </pre>
</div>
```